# Static UITableviewCells glitch when UIElements are added

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, static

I added a UITableViewController and set the type to static. Everything works when there are no UIElements added to the Cells but when one is added, it completely glitches. I deleted all of the delegate methods in the class but the tableview still is messed up. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you've set Custom Row height property.

1. Select cell
2. Open **Size inspector**
3. Set Row Height to 44 (or any other needed size)

[image]